# Guessing Game Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

So i have been learning ruby as of late and i am working on this code for practice purposes but i cannot seems to be able to solve this problem any help would be appreciate it.

This is are the guidelines i am following:

```
clear the screen
greet the player
explain the rules of the game to the player
generate a random number between 0 and x (x being a variable that can be set to any integer)
allow the player n number of guesses (n being a variable)
keep track of the guess history
don't count repeated guesses against the player
congratulate the player when he/she guesses correctly
alert the player when there is only one guess remaining
print the guess history at the end of the game
count number of games won IN A ROW
count number of games won in total
congratulate the play on 3 games won IN A ROW
ask if the player wants to play again
thank the player for playing games if the number of games played is greater than 2
```

please keep in my that this is work in progress and i have not completed all the guideline, however my questions is with one particular part of it.

here is the code:

```
guess = Array.new
puts guess.class
def ask()
      puts "Please answer in a 'y' or 'n' only!"
      puts "Would like to play again?"
end


def guess_check_against()
       g = guess.last
unless guess.include?(g) != guess
       count+=1
else
     puts "sorry you have guessed that number before, Guess Again: "
       guess << gets.to_i
       count+=1
end
end

puts "what is your name?"
user= gets.chomp

puts "Hello #{user}!!"
max_user_attempts = 4
@attempt_counter = 0
directions = "\nLets play a guessing game! You have
#{max_user_attempts.to_s} guesses before you lose."
print directions

g = guess.last
win = 0
count = 0
play = true

while play == true

  puts "Please tell me the max value of the random number: "
    max= gets.to_i
    num= rand(max)
  puts "Ok. The random number is generated between 1 and " + max.to_s + "."
  puts "Make your guess: "
      guess << gets.to_i
          guess_check_against()
          @attempt_counter+=1
    while guess != num && play != false

  if g > num && @attempt_counter < max_user_attempts
    print "That's too high. Guess again: "
    guess << gets.to_i
    guess_check_against()
    @attempt_counter+=1
  elsif g < num && @attempt_counter < max_user_attempts
    print "That's too low. Guess again: "
    guess << gets.to_i
    guess_check_against()
    count+=1
    @attempt_counter+=1
  else
    break
  end

end
 if @attempts_counter >= max_user_attemtps
    puts "Sorry! you lost! Try Again"
      break
 else @attempts_counter <= max_user_attempts      
    puts "Correct! You guessed the answer in " + count.to_s + " tries!"
      win+=1
  end
    if win >= 3
      puts "Congratulation! you have #{win} number of  games in a row"
        ask()
        answer = gets.chomp!

    elsif win < 3
        ask()
        answer = gets.chomp!
    else
        break
      end                   

    if answer == 'n'
            play = false
       break
    end

    if  answer == 'y'
            play = true
            count = 0
    end
 end

 puts "Ok. Goodbye!!"
```

and here is the error i keep receiving when i try to run this program:

```
guessing_game.rb:12:in `guess_check_against': undefined local variable or method `guess' for main:Object (NameError)
    from guessing_game.rb:45:in `<main>'
```

when i try to use irb to run the same scenario it works completely fine.

i can not figure out what i am doing wrong, please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method definition

```
def guess_check_against()
   g = guess.last
  ...
end
```

has its own scope, and the local variable

```
guess = Array.new
```

that you defined outside of it, is not accessible inside the method definition. `guess` is not defined inside the method definition. You can change the code so that the method takes that as an argument, and it will become accessible.

Comment: okay so if i was define the guess = Array.new within the method it should work?

Comment: def guess_check_against(g)
       unless guess.include?(g) != guess
            count+=1   
    else
     puts "sorry you have guessed that number before, Guess Again: "
        guess << gets.to_i
   end
    end 
@sawa
this is what i have done with the code will this work?